# Build-Deploy-Test Workflow does not reach Test Agent

Tags: deployment, tfs, build, automated-tests

at First im New to automated Tests with TFS, so i try actual many Things with try on Error.
But I Hope you can give me some Ideas What i perhaps do wrong.

I have set up a Environment in Microsoft Test Manager like described in serveral Blogs from MSDN. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873102.aspx#Prerequisites for example.

My Infrastructure is as follows: The Build Server and Test Controller are on the Same Machine (Win2012) but my Test Agent(Win2008R2) is an other Machine. Everything is TFS 2013 or VS 2013 Update 3.

I have a Build definition which builds the Tests on the Buildserver into a specified Dropfolder. This is working fine. And a Second Build Definition which uses the LabDefaultTemplate.11 for working with the Environment. Within i specified the Environment, the other Build Definiton a Deployment Script and also my Testplan with the associated Automated Tests.

But if i try to Start my Build-Deploy-Test Workflow i have got two outcomes.
First, without specifed a Deploment Script the Workflow Reaches Test Run and the Workflow became endless (It runs 16 Hours) then i aborted it.
And Second i specified the Deployment Script and now it seems i get the same but on the Deployment Step. I let it Run for almost 20 Minutes and i watched my Agent on VM Console.
All i saw is that he sometimes Disconnected for a short moment and then was Online again.

Now I'm Asking, why this Build Workflow could becomes endless?

The Tests would be CodedUiTests.

Here the Log of the last Run i stopped:

```
20:37 Overall Build Process
20:37 Application Deployment Workflow
00:00 Update Build Number
00:00 Get Build Details
01:00 If Build is needed
01:00 Do Build
00:00 Start Build Workflow
01:00 Wait For Build To Complete
00:00 Set Build Location
00:00 Get Build Location And Build Number
00:00 Compute build location needed
00:00 Compute build path
00:00 If user selected stored environment
00:00 Get Lab Environment Uri
00:00 Get Lab Environment
00:00 If Restore Snapshot
00:00 No Clean Snapshot
00:00 If Virtual Environment
00:00 If deployment or test needed
00:00 Wait For Environment To Be Ready
19:36 If deployment needed
19:36 Do deployment
00:00 Reserve Environment For Deployment
19:36 Deploy Build on Environment
19:36 Deploying Build
19:36 Run Deployment scripts
19:36 Run Deployment Task Deployment Task Logs for Machine: Win2008R2   
00:00 Release Environment From Deployment
```

*If you would need more specific informations please leave a Answer with the needed Things, and i will care about it, but i actual do not know what you could need and don't want to overfill this Question*

Edit Dec 16th 2014:

Here the requested Details:

```
Deploying Build 00:30:00
Run Deployment scripts 00:30:00

Inputs
Values: Win2008R2TA02 | $(BuildLocation)\Uitest\deploymentScript.cmd $(BuildLocation)

Run Deployment Task00:30:00

Inputs
        UseRoleForDeployment: False
        MaxWaitTime: 00:30:00
        ThrowOnError: True
        BuildLocation: \\BuildServer\TFS Build\UiTest.Dev.Build\UiTest.Dev.Build_20141216.1
        LabEnvironmentUri: vstfs:///LabManagement/LabEnvironment/11
        DeploymentScriptDetails: Win2008R2TA02 | $(BuildLocation)\Uitest\deploymentScript.cmd $(BuildLocation)
```

The Deployment Script i found in the Internet, but i thought this could be working.

```
REM set build path
set buildlocation=%1

REM set deployment path
set targetdir="C:\deploy"

REM create deployment directory
if not exist %targetdir% (cmd /c mkdir %targetdir%)

REM copy build to the deployment directory
xcopy /c /y /e %buildlocation%\*.* %targetdir%

REM if you are using a deployment package you can run it here, after you copy it to your deployment directory
```

And i Call it as follows:

```
$(BuildLocation)\Uitest\deploymentScript.cmd $(BuildLocation)
```

In the Eventlog of the Test Controller there are some Errors Repeating while the Build is running: 
Service Control Managar:

> The Visual Studio Test Controller service terminated unexpectedly.  It
>   has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be
>   taken in 0 milliseconds: Restart the service.

.Net Runtime:

> Application: QTController.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException Stack:    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Controller.BuildDropDownloadManager.GetLocalSharePath(System.String)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Controller.DeploymentTaskMonitor.IsUsingServerDrop(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.DeploymentTask)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Controller.DeploymentTaskMonitor.ProvisionBuildSharePermision(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.DeploymentTask)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Controller.DeploymentTaskMonitor.ProcessNewDeploymentTasks()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Controller.DeploymentTaskMonitor.Poll(System.Object)
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(System.Object)

I tried this solution but i does not helping and related to the Link i have no "Web Access" Folder to clear the Cache out.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c1ba09a8-5b8a-4c6d-8635-83085593647b/tfs-2013-deploy-to-testlab-is-failing-labdefaulttemplate11?forum=tfsbuild

I realy stuck on that Problem. Any Help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found the issue. 
The problem was a corrupt Visual Studio and MTM Installation on the Buildserver where also the TestController is installed.

If you stumble on this problem, try the following things.
 - Are all Components on the same Version (in my case 2013 Update 3) Check also Agent and Controller (in it's Configuration Dialog you find a About Button)
 - open the MTM on the Server and Check if it can switch between different testplans of the project (in m case that bring up an error, and thats why the Controller could not deliver the Cases to the Agent.)

if it is like in my case so try a uninstallation and reinstallation of Visual Studio and MTM
My order was to deinstall first MTM then VS after that install VS then MTM then the actual Update.

Answer (score 0):

The build report log on visual studio is not that great. Have you checked the log on the tfs website? (build failed report -> diagnostics -> view log or on the website under builds -> definition -> diagnostics)

Have you set the timeout for the deployment script? 16 hours is a long time. 
also can you link the deployment code to the script. Do you have any other tests that do run on the agent? Have you checked the login/password and deactivated the login screen on the agent because tfs has a problem accessing this.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I Checked the Log on tfs Website and there are nearly the same details as on the Build Report page, if you hit View Log. I checked also the inputs in the Step which fails (Run Deployment Task) and the parent one (Run Deployment scripts).

Yes i Have set the Timeout for Deployment but the 16 Hours was before i added Deployment Script cause i tried first without it.
Sidequestion, do i always need a Deployment script?

In the Situation i entered in this Company no Tests where running and now i try to get it to work, so no Tests working right now.

Comment: Sorry for Doublepost but i cant edit my Comment anymore.
Yes, the Agent is configured to login automaticaly and to ensure disabled Screensaver.

Comment: No you don't need a Deployment script. (can be usefull when you use snapshots) Have you tried to make a small test (for example open notepad...) and let it run on your system. If the basics fail its easier to find the problem. About the script, is it included in your visual studio project? (I use "$(BuildLocation)\Resources\Bat Files\Script.cmd" /Y) and this does work. And in your cmd file you use the %buildlocation%  and i do not know if this works. (have to test it myself...)  Just checking some things I had problems with.

Comment: Ok, i removed the Deployment Script, cause i actual not use snapshots and my target is to get it run first before it get complex. Trying this get me the result that it is still endless but it say it would "Run Tests" also telling me that: 
The following Suite ID will be used to create the test run: 2579
The following test run was created: ID: 2661
and there it stucks. Event log from Test Controller seems quiet but at the Agent it says still:
"Unable to connect to the controller on 'BuildServer:6901'. Cannont communicate with the Controller due to version mismatch"

Comment: Cannot communicate with the Controller due to version mismatch means you might be running 2 different versions. can you verify this? the tfs version and visual studio version?

Comment: I Checked the Versions and found out that a Visual Studio on Test Controller Machine and also my Client on the Personal Machine where not Updated, but after Update and Reboot from both Machines it still wont running on the Agent. The Error Message of different Version is gone, and no new Messages came up. I haven't any idea what could be the Problem. Situation in the Build is like before, it stucked as it ment to do tests but the Agent Idle and also the Environment shows no Change in Status...